# How to Create Excel type navigation in asp.net grid

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am currently working on asp.net. I have a grid view where I have multiple textboxes in different columns.

What I want is an **Excel Type Navigation** in my gridview textboxes.

Here is my gridview textbox code:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="right" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center">
    <HeaderTemplate>Units Invoiced</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvUnit" runat="server" 
                CssClass="textBox nav textboxfocus" 
                Text='<%# Eval("Units Invoiced")%>'
                Style="text-align: right;" onBlur="CalculateRAmt(this);">
           </asp:TextBox>
           <AJAXT:FilteredTextBoxExtender runat="server" ID="AtxtInvUnit" 
               ValidChars="0123456789" FilterMode="ValidChars" FilterType="Custom" 
               TargetControlID="txtInvUnit">
           </AJAXT:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want it to work like if the user presses down the arrow key from keyboard then focus should move to next row text box of same column.

I want to do this using **JQuery** or **Javascript**.

Can anybody help me. Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Can we see what code you would start with?

Comment: Not yet. But i want to do like this because there so much of rows.